# Why is the output voltage out of phase with the input even though the primary and the secondary are wound the same?

Tags: transformer

[image: schematic]

Why, in the second circuit, is the output is out of phase with the input even though the primary and the secondary are wound the same way?

Source:

Circuit Analysis: Theory and Practice, Robbins and Miller, page 989, 2nd edition.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The output waveform deduced from the dot convention in a transformer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/700317/the-output-waveform-deduced-from-the-dot-convention-in-a-transformer)

Answer (score 2):

This image from [www.electricaltechnology.org](https://www.electricaltechnology.org/2013/12/transformer-phasing-the-dot-notation-and-dot-convention.html) shows winding current direction, as related to the little dots next to the windings in the schematic:

[image]

That means the second circuit in your example will have potential differences in phase, not the left one. I think your own diagram is incorrect.

Considering current direction, I'm sure you can see why loads connected to those secondaries would develop opposite polarity voltages in each case.

Comment: What do you think about what's in here https://circuitdigest.com/article/understanding-dot-convention-in-transformers   ?

Comment: @Jack I'll have to take a back seat here. I love the idea that current enters where the dot is (simple to remember and understand), but it's not my understanding. I won't fight in either camp, in the same way I won't fight for the spelling of "organis/ze".

Answer (score 2):

> *Why, in the second circuit, is the output is out of phase with the
> input even though the primary and the secondary are wound the same
> way?*

The book has got it badly wrong.

Dots indicate two things: -

- Current entering the driven dot will exit at the secondary dot (if there is a load)
- Voltage at the driven dot will be in phase with voltage at the secondary dot

**Alternative way of looking at things**

Imagine you are winding an inductor but, instead of using a single wire you wind two identical wires at the same time. The wires are of course insulated from each other but, pretty-much occupy the same space running parallel around the core.

If you measured the inductance of one winding it might be 1 mH. If you measure the inductance of the other winding it will also be the same inductance (1 mH). If you then joined the two wires together at their ends, would we expect to witness problems and the inductance falls to zero, or would we expect the two wires to behave exactly like one single wire (just as if they were electrically connected throughout the winding).

Answer: They would behave the same as one wire and, if we split them with one being driven and one being measured we would see this: -

[image]

Image from [my basic website](http://www.stades.co.uk/#transformers)

If I were to mark dots on my diagram both would be at the same end. If I were to add a load we would get this: -

[image]

In other words, when primary current enters the dot, secondary current exits the dot.

Comment: Am sorry Andy, but I have found an explanation in this site that answered my question and confirmed what's in the book https://circuitdigest.com/article/understanding-dot-convention-in-transformers

Comment: @Jack don't apologize for getting information from another site. However, you still have a duty to this site unless you are going to remove your question (not recommended).

Comment: What i am saying is that the site I put the link of confirms the book, so what you think of what's mentioned there?

Comment: It looks like it agrees with my answer so, what specifically is confusing?

Comment: The site says the output not only does it depend on where the dots are, it also depends on how you connect the meter with wich you measure the voltage

Comment: So given that, the book is right indeed because even though in the second circuit the dots are aligned, the postive of the meter (+) isn't connected  to where the current is entering. So, the output will be reflected wrt the input like it is the case here.

Comment: No, I'm sorry but the image in your question is plainly wrong. The 2nd image has the secondary reversed but the meter still makes the original connections hence, the output looks inverted to the input. No problem with the 2nd image but, big problem with the book picture in your question.

Comment: @Jack If we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

Comment: @Jack the above "take note" is still valid even though the question is closed (I voted to reopen btw). Nice scrap loco in your avatar. Where was it taken? Maybe you dob't know and the formula is more relevant.

Answer (score 1):

The dot on the winding indicates winding start. In the first example the dots are at opposite ends in the second they are at the same end.

The normal convention is that if both the dots are at the same end the output voltage is in phase with the input voltage. So the diagram is incorrect.

Comment: The second even though they're wound the same, the output is reflected wrt the input, why?

Comment: @Jack Current in the two secondaries are in opposite directions, so the load will develop the opposite polarity voltage.

Comment: @RoyC I agree, that diagram seems wrong.

Comment: Look at what this site has to say about that https://circuitdigest.com/article/understanding-dot-convention-in-transformers

Comment: Read it again.     "When the dots are placed next to the top ends of the primary and secondary windings as shown below, it indicates that the polarity of the instantaneous voltage across the primary winding will be the same as that across the secondary winding. Meaning the phase shift between the primary and secondary winding will be zero (in- Phase), and the direction of the Secondary current (Is) and Primary current (Ip) will be the same.​"